# How can I use vibration of an iPhone for my HTML / Javascript game?

Tags: javascript, html5, iphone

I'm building a web game. I'm trying to use the **iPhone's vibration functionality**. How would I go about doing this seeing I want to package and **deploy** this game **to the App Store**. Is there a secured way to do this?

Comment: First hit on google: https://davidwalsh.name/vibration-api

Comment: I'm removing that second question since it seems unrelated & something to ask separately.

Comment: @Bálint - I'm fully aware of David Walsh' blog post. I know the HTML5 vibration spec. It is not supported well cross browser and the fact that I need to have the game deployed in the App Store is actually the point of me asking.

Comment: @doppelgreener - See my comment on Bálint. It actually is relevant.

Comment: @Kriem Thanks, that makes sense. I thought you were asking separately about regular packaging and deployment of an app, but this clarifies it. :)

Comment: @doppelgreener I rephrazed my question to make it a bit more clear. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have found out, the [W3C Vibration API](https://w3c.github.io/vibration/) is not supported in the iOS Safari browser (as reported here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=vibration).

However, you've pointed out that you plan to package your app for the iOS App Store. *To do this, you'll need to package your "web game" into an appropriate native container for installation on the phone*.

You could try to write your own app using the WKWebView component and catching JavaScript events to handle the vibration function natively, but there are already several app frameworks that do that for you. Each of them supports accessing the phone's vibration function, either from JavaScript or via native code. I'd recommend experimenting with them both and going with whichever works best for you:

- Adobe PhoneGap
- React Native

Comment: Intel_XDK its another one.